# modifying a Cake PHP controller file

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I am not a Cake PHP programmer, but I have a live website (developed by a guy who has since left) to which I need to make a modification. I need to add an if statement to a block of code in a controller file in app/controller folder. I know this may sound daft, but if I add any code (assuming my new code logic is correct) to this controller file, is there any chance of the script failing? Is there any cache mechanism in Cake or something that may break that I should be worried about?

Comment: Of course you can break stuff if you do the wrong thing. But it's not very likely, Cake isn't *that* different from normal PHP. Just try it and come back with actual problems, if you face any.

Answer (score 1):

Controller files do not get cached, so any change you make you should see live.  But yes, obviously if you write bad code there is chance the script will break.  But if you are just adding an if block you shouldn't have too much trouble.